# nginx won't serve json file unless specifying .json in url

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have the following nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name dummy_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
      }

      default_type 'application/json';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
      if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)" ) {
        set  $last_path_component  $1;
      }

      try_files $last_path_component.json $last_path_component.json =404;
    }
  }
```

I would like to serve `healthcheck.json` when `localhost:8080/v1/healthcheck` is requested.
However, nginx refuses to serve any json file if I'm not explicitly hitting `localhost:8080/v1/healthcheck.json`, otherwise it logs file not found, and the response is nginx's 404 page.
If I add .json at the end of the url, the file is magically found and great magic happens.
I tried forcing `application/json` type, as well as changing the `try files` row to explicitly return the file I would like to return (so I've set `try_files healthcheck.json =404;`) all returns the same issue.

I'm quite lost.. anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually an expected behavior with this config. 
So, what you are doing, is stripping the URL and then passing it to `try_files`.
But there is nothing in `try_files` to handle files without an extension. To do that, modify it like this

```
try_files $last_path_component $last_path_component.json $last_path_component.json =404;
```

This will allow you to serve `.json` files without extension. **However**, this will not serve the same `.json` file with or without extension. The `try_files` directive checks the existence of the files and serves them in this order. So if you have `healthcheck.json` and try to access it via `localhost:8080/v1/healthcheck`it will still fail. So you need to have `healthcheck` end-point to be actually without an extension on the server for it to be accessible.

If you want to handle both variations, with or without extension, you might want to strip the `.json` part first like this

```
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.json(\?.*)?$) {
         return 302 /$1$2;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri.json =404;

    }
```

Comment: works like charm!.
Tbh I'm not sure about the explanation. I still can't understand why it wont serve the json just yet

Comment: @ran the config you posted didn't handle the files without extension at all. Check out the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) regarding `try_files` directive